# System of linear differential equations eigenproblem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

In the Smith and Young 2001 paper on the Barotropic tide they have the governing equations...

\begin{array}{rcl}
  u_t-f_0v+p_x & = & 0
\\v_t+f_0u+p_y & = & 0
\\p_z &= &b
\\b_t+wN^2 & = & 0
\\u_x+v_y+w_z & =& 0
\end{array}

with BCs 
\begin{equation}
w(x,y,0,t)=0 ; w(x,y,-H,t)=U \cdot \nabla h
\end{equation}

From here they "project onto vertical modes associated with the stratification N(z)". and get the functions defined by the eigenproblem

\begin{equation}
\frac{d^2a_n}{dz^2}+\frac{N^2}{\lambda_n^2 f_0^2}a_n = 0,     a_n(0)=a_n(-H)=0
\end{equation}

Could someone explain to me where this has come from?

Comment: They are assuming the solution has a specific form which reduces the system into an infinite system of ODEs